# iBooks preview not working?

Tags: macos, ipad, books

I recently converted one of my books into an iBooks format using Author. However when I connected to my iPad and went into 'preview', I saw my device, clicked it, but the 'preview' button to enable the previewing process was faded and I could not click it. Has anyone actually used the preview feature enough to give me some help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue with my iMac running Lion and iPad 1. The iPad was visible but greyed out, as was the preview button.

Here's what worked for me:

- Connect iPad to Mac
- Open iBooks on iPad
- Click on preview in Author
- Close iBooks on iPad
- Cancel preview and tap on preview again
- Open iBooks on iPad again

Not sure why or how, but it worked for me.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, really big thanks for the help. However after further study I realized I installed iBooks 2 on my iPhone but forgot on iPad. I tried just about all I could and finally solved the trouble. However for your troubles I will make your answer my accepted answer. Again, thanks!

Comment: How do you cancel a preview? I don't see this option.

Answer (score 0):

The key to making the iPad available in the preview selection box of iBooks Author was quitting iBooks Author, and restarting.  Now I can preview the latest version of my book on iPad Pro.

Comment: Did you restart the iPad?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  Then I realized that I had "Hide my iCloud books" enabled.  Once I disabled that feature, I was able to see my unpublished iBook.